# What is correct syntax for Jquery done()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following syntax:
[image]

And am receiving the following error on line 6:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
```

I read the api docs on done() and I can't see what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Don't post code as screenshots. It's impossible to copy/quote it.

Answer (score 5):

```
$.post(path).done(funtion(data) { ....
                     ^----notice any missing characters here, a "c" perhaps?
```

JS is trying to call a function called "funtion", which means that the `{` afterwards is illegal syntax. Since it parses out that syntax error first, it doesn't get to the point of being to able to tell you that "funtion" doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks mate. Is there a more effective way to do "button.parent().parent()"?

Answer (score 3):

You wrote `funtion` instead of `function`.

```
$.post(path).done(function(data) { console.log(data) });
```